# CMSIS API for "taskENTER_CRITICAL()" in FreeRTOS

Tags: freertos, cmsis

As I know, in FreeRTOS, these are two methods `taskENTER_CRITICAL()` and `taskEXIT_CRITICAL()` which are used to enter and exit the critical section. Is there any wrapper for these two methods in the CMSIS API?

Just like the `osKernelStart()` is the CMSIS API to wrap the `vTaskStartScheduler()` in the FreeRTOS.

Answer (score 0):

At least in v2 there is
`int32_t osKernelLock(void)`

I haven't found something similar in v1.

[CMSIS-RTOS2](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS2/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__KernelCtrl.html#ga948609ee930d9b38336b9e1c2a4dfe12)

Comment: It says *"This function cannot be called from Interrupt Service Routines."* AFAIK, `taskENTER_CRITICAL()` doesn't have such a restriction.

Comment: The FreeRTOS website says:

*"The taskENTER_CRITICAL() and taskEXIT_CRITICAL() macros provide a basic critical section implementation that works by simply disabling interrupts, either globally, or up to a specific interrupt priority level."*

So, in my humble opinion, the `taskENTER_CRITICAL() ` not only *"lock all task switches"*, but also disable all the interrupts from the peripheral.

If we want to prevent the tasks switch, seems there is another macro `vTaskSuspendAll` for that.